# Asymptotic expansion of a double integral with a cancellation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

I have an integral $$I_\lambda=\iint_{[-1,1]^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x+y|}}|x|^{i\lambda}|y|^{-i\lambda}dxdy$$ which I want to expand to a series in powers of $\lambda$. However, when $x$ approaches $-y$ The factors in power $\lambda$ cancel each other so I guess that $I_\lambda=a |\lambda|^{-\frac 12}+O(|\lambda|^{-\frac32})$. Am I right? How can I justify any asymptotic on this integral?